# Gradle plugin 3.0.0 beta 4: "buildTypeMatching has been removed. Use buildTypes.<name>.fallbacks"

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-build-type

After updating to Gradle plugin 3.0.0 beta 4 our build failed with the following message:

> buildTypeMatching has been removed. Use buildTypes.<name>.fallbacks

Our libraries have `release` and `debug` `buildType`s, but our app has two additional `buildType`s: 'releaseWithLogs' and 'debugMinified'.

Snippet of our **app** Gradle file:

```
android {
    // ...
    buildTypeMatching 'releaseWithLogs', 'release'
    buildTypeMatching 'debugMinified', 'debug'

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // ...
        }
        debugMinified {
            // ...
        }
        release {
            // ...
        }
        releaseWithLogs {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26):

After some investigation, the following announcement has been found: [Android Studio 3.0 Beta 4 is now available](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/09/android-studio-30-beta-4-is-now.html). There, it mentions:

> You now provide fallbacks for missing build types and flavors using `matchingFallbacks` (which replaces `buildTypeMatching` and `productFlavorMatching`). You also provide the default selection and fallbacks for missing dimensions using `missingDimensionStrategy` (which replaces `flavorSelection`).

So, our previous **app** build.gradle gets converted to:

```
android {
    // ...
    //buildTypeMatching 'releaseWithLogs', 'release' // remove this
    //buildTypeMatching 'debugMinified', 'debug'     // remove this

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            // ...
        }
        debugMinified {
            // ...
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']    // instead use this
        }
        release {
            // ...
        }
        releaseWithLogs {
            // ...
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']  // instead use this
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that, instead of saying that `buildType` `releaseWithLogs` will also match with `release` (`buildTypeMatching 'releaseWithLogs', 'release'`), we specify the match inside the `buildType` itself. Same for `debugMinified` matching `debug`. Also notice that there's no need to include this in `release` and `debug` `buildType`s, as they already match.

Comment: This is not specified in the documentation, but does `matchingFallbacks = ['...'] ` need to be the last instruction of the `buildType` as it didn't work for me when I set it as the first one?

Comment: @Eselfar I don't think so. Could you open a new question with additional information so I can try to help and paste the link here as a comment?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I don't see the relationship with just the information you provide. I guess you have searched in SO for it and you've got here. Could you provide more details? Maybe would be good to open a specific question, referencing this answer.